# unable to make it so docker starts up automatically

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd, ubuntu-20.04, systemctl

Per https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot I tried `sudo systemctl enable docker`. I then restarted and typed in `sudo docker ps` and...  nothing.

When I typed in `sudo systemctl | grep running` I got the following:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

Any ideas?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 / Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to follow a Docker guide that assumes you are running a real Linux distro, and not a virtualized one like WSL.

You would need to install Docker for Windows, which now has support for WSL2 backends. A guide is here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

After you do that, you would be able to run `docker` commands in your WSL2 shell.